# Deadlocks in SOLR

Tags: solr, deadlock

We are seeing thread pool exhausted on Tomcat. And the service hangs with high latency.

With this exception. Any help is appreciated.
    Thread Name:http-8080-541
    ID:610
    Time:Thu May 15 13:21:34 CDT 2014
    State:WAITING
    Priority:5

```
sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:834)
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireQueued(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:867)
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquire(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1197)
java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync.lock(ReentrantLock.java:214)
java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lock(ReentrantLock.java:290)
java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Segment.scanAndLock(ConcurrentHashMap.java:537)
java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Segment.remove(ConcurrentHashMap.java:553)
java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.remove(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1111)
org.apache.lucene.util.WeakIdentityMap.reap(WeakIdentityMap.java:238)
org.apache.lucene.util.WeakIdentityMap.put(WeakIdentityMap.java:130)
org.apache.lucene.store.ByteBufferIndexInput.buildSlice(ByteBufferIndexInput.java:236)
org.apache.lucene.store.ByteBufferIndexInput.clone(ByteBufferIndexInput.java:187)
org.apache.lucene.store.ByteBufferIndexInput.clone(ByteBufferIndexInput.java:39)
org.apache.lucene.codecs.BlockTreeTermsReader$FieldReader$SegmentTermsEnum.initIndexInput(BlockTreeTermsReader.java:1314)
org.apache.lucene.codecs.BlockTreeTermsReader$FieldReader$SegmentTermsEnum$Frame.loadBlock(BlockTreeTermsReader.java:2348)
org.apache.lucene.codecs.BlockTreeTermsReader$FieldReader$SegmentTermsEnum.seekExact(BlockTreeTermsReader.java:1745)
org.apache.lucene.index.AtomicReader.docFreq(AtomicReader.java:94)
org.apache.lucene.index.BaseCompositeReader.docFreq(BaseCompositeReader.java:118)
org.apache.lucene.search.vectorhighlight.FieldTermStack.<init>(FieldTermStack.java:116)
org.apache.lucene.search.vectorhighlight.FastVectorHighlighter.getFieldFragList(FastVectorHighlighter.java:193)
org.apache.lucene.search.vectorhighlight.FastVectorHighlighter.getBestFragments(FastVectorHighlighter.java:184)
org.apache.solr.highlight.DefaultSolrHighlighter.doHighlightingByFastVectorHighlighter(DefaultSolrHighlighter.java:588)
org.apache.solr.highlight.DefaultSolrHighlighter.doHighlighting(DefaultSolrHighlighter.java:413)
org.apache.solr.handler.component.HighlightComponent.process(HighlightComponent.java:139)
org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:208)
org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:135)
org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1820)
org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:656)
org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:359)
org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:155)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:465)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: Can you add some additional info? Version of Solr and JDK? Standalone Solr or Solr Cloud? Anything unusual going on when you see this? one time event or does it happen frequently? Does it crash when this happens or do you just see this in the logs?

Comment: tven, did you ever solve this issue?  We are experiencing similar issues with Tomcat/Catalina/ColdFusion 10.

Comment: It was a rogue query that was very heavy and resource intensive that caused issues.